# unsubscribe via Update Method and Subscriber Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, php

I am using the Exact Target SOAP API, on stack 7 (S7)

I am trying to modify the status of a subscriber via the update method in order to unsubscribe a subscriber. I know that to unsubscribe you need to use the LogUnsubEvent but that is used to track the unsubscribers...

I am confused. If I can create a subscriber without creating a event (like a LogSubEvent) why can't I use the same object with the update method in order to make the status change?

So I guess my question is: Can I do this, unsubscribe someone, in ANY OTHER way (preferably with the Update method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the Lists associated with a Subscriber and mark the status on each one as 'Unsubscribed'. All Subscribers will be one of those Lists.

The LogUnsubEvent is better since it includes a reason and will note the change properly in the Tracking Extracts.

Comment: Thank you for your support. Is there any way that I can add attributes to a list via a API call? So not update a specific attribute of a subscriber, but add or delete attributes to a specific list?

Comment: I believe you can add Profile Attributes via API.  Unlike Data Extensions, all Lists share the same Attributes.